# Matplotlib not respecting Pandas categorical value order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple data frame with one column SIZE of categorical values (SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE) and another column VALUE of integers. When I create a scatter plot of VALUE as a function of SIZE, the order of the categories shown on the X axis will change, depending on the SIZE of the first row in the dataframe. I made sure to tell Pandas the explicit "ordering" of the SIZE category values.

To see this in action, use the following code snippet

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'SIZE': ['MEDIUM', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE', 'SMALL', 'LARGE', 'LARGE'], 
                   'VALUE': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

# Convert to categorical data type and define the order
df['SIZE'] = pd.Categorical(df['SIZE'], categories=['SMALL', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE'], ordered=True)

print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
print(df.SIZE.describe)
```

This produces the following output:

```
SIZE     category
VALUE       int64
dtype: object

     SIZE  VALUE
0  MEDIUM      1
1  MEDIUM      2
2   LARGE      3
3   SMALL      4
4   LARGE      5
5   LARGE      6

<bound method NDFrame.describe of 0    MEDIUM
1    MEDIUM
2     LARGE
3     SMALL
4     LARGE
5     LARGE
Name: SIZE, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['SMALL' < 'MEDIUM' < 'LARGE']>
```

Looking at this, it appears that all is well. But when I plot using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df.SIZE, df.VALUE)
```

I get a graph where the first category on the X axis is 'MEDIUM', not 'SMALL'.

[image]

If I simply change the SIZE of the first row to 'SMALL', i.e.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SIZE': ['SMALL', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE', 'SMALL', 'LARGE', 'LARGE'], 
                   'VALUE': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

and rerun the rest of the code I'll get a graph that has the proper order.

[image]

I'm apparently missing some nuance in Matplotlib. I'm using Matplotlib 3.4.3 and Pandas 1.3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib doesn't care about `Categorical` dtype. You should sort your dataframe first by `SIZE`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = df.sort_values('SIZE')
ax.scatter(df.SIZE, df.VALUE)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. Interestingly enough, plotting using Pandas, e.g. df.plot.scatter('SIZE', 'VALUE') has the same behavior - and Pandas does know about the categorical dtype but apparently doesn't care about the order. Seaborn gets it right and preserves the order.